# Linux whiptail or dialog with menu and input together

Tags: linux, dialog, whiptail

I want to use the 'whiptail' package to generate a menu box and input box simultaneously on screen. Is this possible? Or maybe with dialog? I can't find any example of this.

I want something like this:
Menu item 1
Menu item 2
menu item 3

if none of the above, type your own:
Inputbox:

The user could either select one of the entries from the menu or type in his own input. How do I do this?

(I did see the dialog 'inputmenu' widget, but with the Ok/rename/cancel, its a bit clunky.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--inputmenu` option in [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) is the closest fit; anything more would require a custom application.  Regarding the "Ok/rename/cancel", there is some flexibility (see [manual page)](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-Common-Options):

> `--nocancel`
>
> Suppress the "Cancel" button in checklist, inputbox and menu box
>   modes.  A script can still test if the user pressed the ESC  key
>   to cancel to quit.
>
> `--extra-label` *string*
>
> Override  the  label used for "Extra" buttons.  Note: for input-menu widgets, this defaults to "Rename".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know of a better tool?

Comment: No - as I said, you could make a *custom application* to do exactly what you want.